# Cannot get value of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have implemented this to get value of checked checkboxes in array but dont know where i am wrong i am getting array empty

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="-1" id="-1" /> OPD CONSULTANCY <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" value="-2" id="-2" /> DOCTOR VISIT <br />

<script>
  function allcheckedData() {
        var allVals = [];
        var checkedVals = [];

        $('#all input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('#all :checked').each(function () {
            checkedVals.push($(this).val());
        })
} 
</script>
```

Comment: You need to `push($(this).is(':checked'))`

Comment: Vastly more efficient: `if (this.checked) allVals.push(this.value)`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/chfsynxq/1/ - just fine

Comment: How are you using the arrays? They're local variables, so they won't be visible outside the function.

Comment: Ok guys i got my mistake the small mistake is i forgot to put id = "All" to the parent tag of checkbox